# Getting a Camera error 100 and a Method called after release error

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder

I'm playing with the google tutorial on using video recorders but I can't get it to work anyhow. I first keep getting at Method called after release error, for the camera preview which I tracked down to realize that mCamera.stoppreview() doesn't work before the startpreview is called again onSurfaceChanged(). Also I get a Camera 100 error with mediaserver died, camera server died and  icamera died when MediaRecorder.start() is called. I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is my CameraActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private Camera mCamera;
     private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
     private CameraPreview mPreview;
     private static final String TAG = "Message";
     public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
     public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
     private boolean isRecording = false;
     Button captureButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.preview);
            System.out.println("Going to get the camera");


            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            //mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

            preview.addView(mPreview);
          //  setPreviewCallback(null);

           captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
            captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                         if (isRecording) {
                                // stop recording and release camera
                                mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                                mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                                // inform the user that recording has stopped
                                captureButton.setText("Capture");
                                isRecording = false;
                            } else {
                                // initialize video camera
                                releaseCamera();

                                if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                                    System.out.println("Starting to record");
                                    // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                                    // now you can start recording
                                    mMediaRecorder.start();

                                    // inform the user that recording has started
                                    captureButton.setText("Stop");
                                    isRecording = true;
                                } else {
                                    // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                                    System.out.println("Recording failed");
                                    releaseMediaRecorder();
                                    // inform user
                                }
                            }
                        }

                }
            );
    }
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
            System.out.println("This is the camera "+c);// attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            System.out.println("Didn't get the camera ");
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        /*CameraPreview preview;
        preview=new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);*/
        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        System.out.println("About to preview");
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
        System.out.println("Preview worked");
        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
        releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            System.out.println("Picture received");
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
                return;
            }

            try {
                System.out.println("Saving");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };



    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
        System.out.println("Trying to save picture");
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

and this is my CameraPreview class

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "Message";
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        /*mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();*/
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            System.out.println("Stop preview didn't work ");


        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:text="Capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all: `FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview)`most certainly doesn't work. You can't cast a SurfaceView into a FrameLayout.

Comment: try removing this lines // initialize video camera                 releaseCamera(); that is on the else of  if (isRecording)

Comment: @mirco.widmer Well that worked when I did the camera application.

Comment: Can you post your xml layout?

Comment: @mirco.widmer Yep. I just did.

Comment: @Tobiel Doing that creates a nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to fix this issue by removing the call to mCamera.release() in onPause(). Here's some code:

```
//kv Only call release here if we're running an OS later than Gingerbread, otherwise, camera will freeze
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1)
{
    mCamera.release();
}
```